# How to write a service in single place and use it everywhere in express js backend?

Tags: node.js, express

I need to do something like this in my app:

```
fetch (reactjs_client) -> internal api ---express_backend---> routes mapper -> handler -> return serviceClient.request(..data)
```

and in handler, to call our internal services, we do

```
serviceClient.create(configs) // 1. trying to move to a common place
serviceClient.request(req, res, path, otherConfigs)
.then(res=> {
    // 2. different handlers have different path
    response.json())
}
.catch(err=>{
    //error handler
    //construct message and send back
})
```

Now for different handlers (different js files), I need to make request. How do I put that creation of client instance and related configs in a common place so every handler can use it and every time, it does not creates multiple instances, rather is reused. Request (2) has to be made multiple times as it sounds, its individual to every call from UI, unlike 1.

Please try to explain as simple as possible, as I am a first timer in nodejs.

Comment: Try to explain better, give a full code example of the nodejs side

Comment: Ok give me some time, I'll try to do it once I'm free from an urgent work.